# Where is $targetframeworkversion$ being set in vstemplates?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-templates

I made a new project template and I do see a usage of $targetframeworkversion$ all around the code. The thing I can't find is where this value is being set and how to change it?

Thanks

Comment: Inside the Visual Studio project system.  You can't see it, only the end result.  Replaced by the .NET Framework combobox value shown at the top of the "New Project" dialog.  Avoid asking an XY question.

Comment: I'm currently getting in the wizard in the replacment dictonary the 4.5 as value. I need to update it do 4.5.1. Where and how should I alter this value? What is an XY question?

Comment: @MaiOM I'm seeing the same thing. I'm using Visual Studio 2019. The Add Project dialog no longer has a drop down list for the target framework. Evidently, this value defaults to v4.5. Not sure why as I have older and newer frameworks installed.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer. It is set in the new project window, on the project creation.

Check this image:

[image]

Choosing the value in the combo box will influence the $targetframeworkversion$.

Hope it helps

Cheers